# Multiple pattern validators for a single input

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, validation

I have an input field where I need to set validations. I have used 2 patterns for the same:

- ^[1-9][0-9]*$
- ^\s|\s$

How do I combine these into one or is there a way to use them together?

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom password validation.

```
<mat-form-field>
        <input type="password" name="password" ngModel matInput placeholder="Password" #passwordInput="ngModel" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}$" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="passwordInput.invalid">Should contain; 8 characters,
          a number, a special character , a lower letter and a upper letter.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine regular expressions with the `|` operator. Like this:

```js
/(^[1-9][0-9]*$)|(^\s|\s$)/
```

For more info about the RegExp operators check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp).